# Does the STM32F469I DISCOVERY board allows the user to perform Digital to Analog Conversion?

Tags: stm32, dac, stm32f4, stm32f4-discovery

I have a question on DAC (Digital to Analog Conversion) capability of the STM32F496I DISCOVERY board, which uses the STM32F469NIH6 (216 pins) microcontroller.

According to the [microcontroller's user manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f469be.pdf), the PA4 and PA5 pins provide the DAC function. Please note that PA4 pin can provide both the DAC_OUT1 and ADC12_INT4 functions. According to the [STM32F469I DISCOVERY board's user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00218846.pdf), the PA4 is connected to the A5 pin of the CN8 Arduino connector. The function of the A5 pin is defined as ADC12_INT4 (Analog to Digital Conversion) and not DAC_OUT1 (Digital to Analog Conversion).

My question is :

Does the STM32F469I DISCOVERY board allow the user to perform DAC operations through the PA4 pin of the microcontroller (A5 pin of the CN8 Arduino connector) or not?

If yes, How is it possible to change the function of A5 pin from ADC12_INT4 to DAC_OUT1 on the CN8 Arduino connector of the STM32F469I DISCOVERY board?

Comment: If the datasheet says this pin has XX, YY and ZZ functions, it means one function can be used at a time. The magic is in your code.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. So as you said, the specific function of the PA4 MCU pin (here the DAC function) can be selected / activated through the software programming of the board.

Comment: Yes, but calling it firmware programming is more appropriate. :) There might be some example code provided by ST for your board.

Comment: And a small note: enter twice to begin a new paragraph.